# (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel

hay,, when i click EDIT button , the error geting notfoundhttpexception
.
my route

```
Route::get('kontak','Kontak@index');
Route::get('kontak_create','Kontak@create');
Route::post('kontak','Kontak@store')->name('kontak');
Route::delete('kontak','Kontak@destroy')->name('kontak');
Route::put('kontak_edit','Kontak@edit')->name('kontak_edit');
```

my edit controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = ModelKontak::where('id',$id)->get();

        return view('kontak_edit',compact('data'));
    }
```

my kontak.blade.php

```
...........................
                            <form action="{{ action('Kontak@destroy', $datas->id) }}" method="delete">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                <a href="{{ url('Kontak_edit',$datas->id) }}" class=" btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Yakin ingin menghapus data?')">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.main-section -->
@endsection
```

when i click the EDIT button .. i am getting error like above.. whats problem ? 
i am using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the edit link you make a `GET` request but your route is waiting for a `PUT` request.

In your route file, replace the `put` method by a `get` like so

```
Route::get('kontak_edit/{id}','Kontak@edit')->name('kontak_edit');
```

And in your HTML, the url should be generated with the `route` helper like so

```
{{ route('kontak_edit',$datas->id) }}
```